# buscar un elemento de mongobd con nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

Hola amigos tengo una duda con mongodb como realizar una busqueda de un parametro ej: nombre no por id donde puede monstrarlo en una vista x tengo el siguite codigo en buscar lo tengo como un parametro GET no se si de esta manera es la forma correcta

```
//Ruta para Buscar clientes desde el numero de decumento
router.get('/clients/buscar', isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    const buscar = await clients.findOne({cedula: req.body.cedula});
    res.redirect('/clients/view', {buscar});
});
```

y desde la vista tengo un botton asi

```
<a href="/clients/buscar" class="btn p-1 ml-1 mr-1 btn-secondary">Buscar</a>
```

gracias amigos por su ayudas

Comment: Hola, veo que el método de búsqueda lo implementas en una ruta de tipo `GET`, sin embargo el valor lo quieres cargar desde el `body` de la solicitud: `req.body.cedula`. Por lo general los valores que se envían en el `body` suelen ser por peticiones tipo `POST`. Además, la acción predeterminada de un elemento `anchor`: (`<a href="/clients/buscar"...>`) es una solicitud tipo `GET`. Deberías repasar un poco dichos conceptos. Por último, si el método `findOne()` no retorna un resultado, ¿cómo pretendes hacer el render de la vista?. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras como lo aria o cual seria la mejor forma amigo gracias